# How can I load data to react-stockcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to implement [the basic area chart](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/rrag/react-stockcharts-examples2/tree/master/examples/AreaChart) into my code, but I realize that I have no idea how to add the input to the code. I cloned the AreaChart component and integrated into my view, added as `<AreaChart data={values} ratio={10} width={10} type={'svg'}/>`, but at the time of parsing the data, there is no written instructions on how to parse the data, o a data template, or anything, simply an error. The documentation isn't good either

Is there an example of how the data should be given to the chart?

I'm trying to parse the following json:

```
"stock": [
  {
    "date": 56116,
    "price": 0.431,
    "accuracy": 0.4361,
    "high": 4.1515,
    "low": 1507.9235,
    "open": 1312.0051,
    "close": 1246.5826
  },
  {
    "date": 93492,
    "price": 0.1717,
    "accuracy": 0.1489,
    "high": 1373.5059,
    "low": 974.1351,
    "open": 1412.5995,
    "close": 1447.5179
  },
  {
    "date": 48833,
    "price": 0.5229,
    "accuracy": 0.9701,
    "high": 466.1322,
    "low": 1673.346,
    "open": 1295.6486,
    "close": 67.016
  }]
```

It's formatted correctly or should it have a different format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data format is tsv.

[Demo link](http://rrag.github.io/react-stockcharts/documentation.html#/area_chart)

[tsv sample file used in demo](https://rrag.github.io/react-stockcharts/data/MSFT.tsv)

Comment: It never says it must be tsv. Plus, when it's saved as a variable, it saves it as an object

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reformat your input into tsv.
I found that I only had to format the date differently.

My original input data caused the same input error and was in this format:

```
{
"date": "2018-06-22",
"open": 74.5,
"high": 74.54,
"low": 74.22,
"close": 74.31,
"volume": 553642
}
```

I re-formated it with this code:

```
const IEX_BASE = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/'
const symbol = this.props.cellObject.symbol
const filter = '?filter=date,open,high,low,close,volume'
axios
  .get(`${IEX_BASE}stock/${symbol}/chart/1y${filter}`)
  .then((res) => {
    let values = res.data
    let data = values.map((obj) => {
      let date = obj.date + 'T05:00:00.000Z'
      obj.date = new Date(date)
      return obj
    })
    this.setState({ data })
  })
```

The new data is passed to react-stockcharts with no error. The new format looks like this:

```
{
"date": "2018-06-22T05:00:00.000Z",
"open": 74.5,
"high": 74.54,
"low": 74.22,
"close": 74.31,
"volume": 553642
}
```

I'm not familiar with your date format like "56116", but try this:

```
obj.date = new Date(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

props data expects an array,

```
const parsed_date_your_json=/* preprocess date string to a date object */;
<AreaChart data={your_json['stock']} ratio={10} width={10} type={'svg'}/>
```